# Srun command before running python vscode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, gpu, ssh-config

Currently running some heavy python scripts within the following context -

### setup

1. connecting to an sshProxy server
2. Connecting to the SSH host
3. Calling conda to activate env
4. running the `srun` command to get GPU allocation

```bash
srun -p normal.q --mem=20GB --cpus-per-task=2 --gres=gpu:quadro_rtx_6000:1 /bin/bash -i
```

5. running the python script

I would like to make this process more efficient, and specificly - running the debugs and sanity tests from VScode against the GPU.

### I have succeeded to do

- Add SSH Custom configuration file with

  - ssh keys
  - proxyCommand

  The config file looks something like this

```
Host runningHostWithoutGPU
  HostName host
  User myuser
  ProxyCommand C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\ssh.exe -q -x ProxyHost -W %h:22
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
  RemoteCommand srun -p normal.q --mem=20GB --cpus-per-task=2 --gres=gpu:quadro_rtx_6000:1 /bin/bash -i
```

- The VSCode server is running on the destination host (connection after all the proxy stuff- succeeded)
- Can **edit the files and save them to the destination host**
- The conda Env is recognized in the interpreter settings
- The srun command does not seems to run (the ssh is just to the host and not to the GPU node itself)
- When starting the RUn Python file, the GPU is not being called

### Tried

Tried to also configure a preRunning task to the debugger, which is shell script to just run `srun...` without any change...

Tried to configure a `remoteCommand` attr in the sshconfig. as a result, the regular windows ssh.exe succeeded to do the last hop to the node itself, but the VScode fails to do that....

What can I do?

Thanks
Idan